# Excel - Display date (month to date)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanna insert date column in my sheet. But I only want to display data from year to date and can update automatically. For example: this date column will display data from 1/1/2018 to today (6/6/2018) and then from 1/1/2018 to 7/6/2018 tomorrow (autimatically).

If you know this function, please help me!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumption change as necessary:
Column with dates is column A
First date is in cell A1
In the first cell which should be the start of the year enter the following formula, this will update each year:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)
```

Then underneath that enter the following formula and drag down:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(A1=TODAY(),"",A1+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution if interested. Put the following code in the `ThisWorkbook` object in the `Visual Basic Editor` by pressing `(Alt + F11)`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  '''Change to name of worksheet.

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)  '''Change column if necessary (ex. column h = 8).

    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    If Not rng = Date Then
        iCount = Date - rng.Value
        For i = 1 To iCount
            rng.Offset(i, 0).Value = rng.Value + i
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will run every time you open the workbook. Even if you haven't opened it in several days it will still increment each row in column A by one from the last recorded date. Just type the date in cell `A1`. No formula needed. You will need to save the file with an `.xlsm` file extension (macro-enabled workbook). Hope it helps!